# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in google cloud storage init

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am getting this rather obscure error when I run some code that is supposed to upload just a few files after it has run some rather intense multiprocessing code. I can't make much from the exception. The only little bit of intuition I can give is that it's something to do with the pretty intense software we run just before doing this. I would be happy clarifying anything by answering questions.

Here is the function where it crashes on the import line

```
def upload_run_artifacts(run_dir, run_id):

    print("Uploading run artifacts")
    from google.cloud import storage

    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket(ARTIFACTS_BUCKET)
    glob_path = os.path.join(run_dir, "**")
    print(glob_path)
    for f in glob.glob(glob_path):
        print(f)
        print(f"Uploading {f} to run artifacts bucket")
        with open(f, 'rb') as fp:
            rel_path = f.replace(run_dir, str(run_id))
            blob = bucket.blob(rel_path)
            blob.upload_from_file(fp)
```

And here's the exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/gerard/Git/captain-benchmarker/captain_benchmarker/benchmark.py", line 396, in <module>
    fire.Fire(
  File "/Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 138, in Fire
    component_trace = _Fire(component, args, parsed_flag_args, context, name)
  File "/Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 466, in _Fire
    component, remaining_args = _CallAndUpdateTrace(
  File "/Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 675, in _CallAndUpdateTrace
    component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gerard/Git/captain-benchmarker/captain_benchmarker/benchmark.py", line 340, in benchmark_autopilot
    upload_run_artifacts(run.id, run_dir)
  File "/Users/gerard/Git/captain-benchmarker/captain_benchmarker/benchmark.py", line 41, in upload_run_artifacts
    from google.cloud import storage
  File "/Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import get_distribution
  File "/Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3262, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3245, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3274, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 575, in _build_master
    ws = cls()
  File "/Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 568, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 622, in add_entry
    self.entry_keys.setdefault(entry, [])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**EDIT:**
My setuptools is this (`python -m pip show setuptools`)

```
Name: setuptools
Version: 46.2.0.post20200511
Summary: Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages
Home-page: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools
Author: Python Packaging Authority
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /Users/gerard/miniconda3/envs/benchmarker/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: protobuf, google-auth, google-api-core
```

Comment: What version of `setuptools` is installed? `python -m pip show setuptools`

Comment: Just updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. What's the value of `sys.path` at the beginning of your `upload_run_artifacts` function?

Comment: Ah! I think you're on to something. My path is huge. I am importing an external Python package dynamically and put in a bit of a sys path hack to do so. Let me try and reduce that and get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes! That was the issue. My path was polluted with empty lists and things that were actually files and what have you. If you can convert you comment into answer I'll gladly accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely an invalid value that's been added to your `sys.path`.

If you've manually put something on your `sys.path` (generally discouraged), ensure that the values are *only* [strings or bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html), and that they're valid paths.